# How to return two values from single methods and set two parent class property calling function 1 time?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have class like below:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool performance { get; set; }
        public List<Skills> Skills { get; set; }
    }

 public class Skills
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string skills { get; set; }
        public int Rate { get; set; }
        public int statistics { get; set; }
    }
```

I have 2 static methods in which 1st static is responsible to just add list of skills. Now for each employee I want to set performance property value which 2nd static method will throw along with list of skills.

I have some logics through which i know that when to return false to performance properties and when to set Rate and Statictics to
0 but the only thing I am not getting is how to return list of skills and associated true or false value without being calling my 2nd static method
twice.

**Code**:

```
public static List<Employee> ReturnEmployeeList(List<EmployeesModel> employeesModel)
        {
            var list = new List<Employee>();
            foreach (var item in employeesModel)
            {
                list.Add
                          (
                               new Employee
                               {
                                   EmployeeId = item.EmployeeId,
                                   Version = item.Name,
                                   performance=????, // i want to set this value based on value return by 2nd static method
                                   Skills = ReturnSkillList(item.SkillModels)
                               }
                          );
            }

            return list;
        }


  private static List<Skills> ReturnSkillList(List<SkillModels> skillModel)
        {
            var list = new List<Skills>();
            //Here  i have some logic in which i know when to set Rate and statictics to 0 and return false for performance properties
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: why don't you first compute the skills and then calculate the performance. Call ReturnSkillList(), put it in temp, then find performance.

Comment: Question : is performance based on Skills property ? If yes, why don't you have perfomance as a get only calculated proprerty ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Nope performance is not based on skills property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling that if you would show the logic behind your code it would be possible to refactor it to a state in which a multi valued return type would not be needed - but I'll answer assuming that this is not relevant.

Three possibilities come to mind, none of which is very pretty in my opinion:

- out variable:

  ```
  bool performance;
  Skills = ReturnSkillList(item.SkillModels, out performance);
  ```

  and the function signature is:

  ```
   private static List<Skills> ReturnSkillList(List<SkillModels> skillModel, out bool perf)
  ```
- Tuple:

  ```
  Tuple<List<Skills, bool> temp = ReturnSkillList(item.SkillModels, out performance);
  Skills = temp.Item1;
  performance = temp.Item2;
  ```

  and the function signature is:

  ```
   private static Tuple<List<Skills>, bool> ReturnSkillList(List<SkillModels> skillModel, out bool perf)
  ```
- Dedicated class: Create a simple class with the two relevant properties.

Comment: Why you think that all this 3 options are not pretty.can you please share your thoughts??

Comment: They're ok but usually in these situations refactoring might prevent the need for returning two values.

Comment: Actually if i have to show the logic then it will involve lots of code and i didnt wanted to increase size of my question so didnt provided evrrything

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new Tuple structure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is how:

```
    private static Tuple<bool, List<Skills>> ReturnSkillList(List<SkillModels> skillModel)
    {
        var list = new List<Skills>();
        var performance = false;

        // your logic here

        return new Tuple<bool, List<Skills>>(performance, list); 
    }
```

Then to access performance use the tuple value Item1 and to access the list use Item2 (i.e. a.Item2)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`Tuple<bool, List<Skills>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) stored to a local variable in your loop? Then you can read from it in your constructor.

```
var performanceAndSkills = ReturnPerformanceAndSkills(item.SkillModels);
list.Add(new MockList
         {
             EmployeeId = item.EmployeeId,
             Version = item.Name,
             performance = performanceAndSkills.Item1,
             Skills = performanceAndSkills.Item2,
         });

private static Tuple<bool, List<Skills> ReturnPerformanceAndSkills(List<SkillModel> skills) {}
```